# How to add a popup UIView (of a customized class) on a UIViewController

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I'm new on this, and I would like to get some advice because I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I want to make an app in xcode, with a `UIView` with some items, and when you do something, another `UIView` (smaller than the first) pops up above the first `UIView`. The popup `UIView` would be a customized class.

I have started with the `UIViewController` template and the initial `UIView`, and I have linked all the items in the `.storyboard`, and it works. But when I create my own `UIView` class `(from objective-C class)`, put the second `UIView` over the first in the `storyboard` and link it to my class, something goes wrong.

The `UIView` appears, but when I try to set it to hidden, it doesn't answer. It's like it's not receiving the messages, so I think I don't link it well programmatically and just appears because of the `storyboard`.

I don't know if I have to create another UIViewController instead of the UIView, or if this is the correct path.

Can anybody explain me a little, or just write a little code snippet with the instantiation of the second view and adding it?

Lots of thanks!!

(I paste some code, of the declaration in .h and instantiation in .m)

```
     #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
     #import "EditView.h"

    @interface ReleaseViewController : UIViewController <UIWebViewDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate> {

        IBOutlet UIWebView *web;
        IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;
        IBOutlet EditView *evHack;

    }

    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *web;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchBar *search;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet EditView *evHack;

    @end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    search.delegate = self;
    web.delegate = self;

    evHack = [evHack initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 377)]; 
    [evHack setHidden:YES]; 

}
```

EditView Class (I still have nothing):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface EditView : UIView

@end



#import "EditView.h"

@implementation EditView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        NSLog(@"View created");
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see code, otherwise it could any one of many reasons why it is not working.

Comment: Done :)
I have it all linked in the storyboard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initWithFrame only works when you alloc/init an app. If its already initialized, in this case by the storyboard, just set its frame:

`evHack.frame = CGRectMake(0,44, 320, 377);`

I don't know what it looks like in IB, But setting its frame in code may be redundant if you set it in IB too. To check whether evHack is hooked up right, NSLog evHack in viewDidLoad. If you get `nil` back, it's not hooked up right.

Comment: Thanks!! I supposed that setting it in the storyboard would alloc it, but I thought I had also to initialize it.
I erased the init line and works fine :)
But if I can't init when I set it in the storyboard, how can I initialize parameters in the constructor? Or do I have to create a normal function for it?

Comment: You can't really use a designated initializer in that case. However, usually you can set whatever property you set with a designated initializer just by sending it a message after it's been initialized. Do you want to do anything specific, or was it just a general question?